# Stack trace nodejs REST API errors

Tags: node.js, debugging, stack, trace

How to show stack trace information when there's an error in an api (written in nodejs)? I used curl to issue a post btw.

I tried node's cli parameter, --stack-trace-limit, but nothing shows up except an unfriendly one liner error message.  I could use console.* and debugger lines in the code but it's too time consuming.  I tried node-inspector.  While it has a nice GUI, it crashes quite.  I reckon there has to be an easier way??

Thx. J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing some code it is hard to answer specifically. However you can also get a stack trace using

```
var stack = new Error().stack
```

## Useful Modules

1. [Memwatch](https://github.com/lloyd/node-memwatch) Useful for outputing heap diffs at various places in your code
2. [node heapdump](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump) Allows you to send a `kill -SIGUSR2 [pid]` to a running node process to generate a heapdump which can then be viewed in the Chrome developer tools by opening up the profiles tab and right clicking in the left pane and choosing *Load Profile*
3. [Standard v8 debugger](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) run your process with `node debug module_name.js` Then anywhere you have `debugger;` statement in your code will cause the debugger to break there
4. [node-webkit-agent](https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent) A heap and cpu profiling tool that uses the Chrome developer tools interface to profile your node.js application. Debugging is not currently supported but apparently is on the way
5. [Long Stacktraces](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn) Sometimes you can get errors that don't have any stack associated with them. I have had this problem with http requests sometimes. Longjohn fixes this problem
6. [node-ofe](https://github.com/trevnorris/node-ofe) Automatically generate a heap dump when your app fatally crashes

## Code Structure

The way you write asyncronous node.js code can have a big effect on the ease of debugging. Named functions are good, anonymous highly nested functions are bad. Check out http://callbackhell.com/ for a good guide on how to write clean debuggable node.js code

Comment: Thanks Noah.  I would think there's some flag I can turn on in nodejs that can print stack trace whenever there's an unhandled error.  I'm new to nodejs but I already found debugging has been pretty difficult.  Maybe the async nature...What tool do you use for debugging nodejs?

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I'm sure nodejs newcomers will find it useful.